# Cheap MongoDB replica set with Raspberry Pi, won't it slow down main instance

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi

I have a personal side project with friends and we're trying to keep costs low on it.

It uses MongoDB on a dedicated server and to do a low cost backup, I was thinking about setting a replica set that includes a Raspberry Pi, at my home, running Mongo, on a slow storage.

- The hardware, the internet connection, etc are clearly below the specs of the main instance.
- I have no experience with replica sets.

I am wondering if having a slow system, within the set, could potentially slow down the main instance? or would the slow instance eventually catch up, whenever, without hurting the main system?

You can abstract the whole Raspberry Pi from the equation and imagine one of the machine in the replica set is super slow behind a much slower connection.

Bonus question: has anyone done this yet?

Comment: While this is a better question for DBA StackExchange since it is about database deployment rather than programming, the general answer on outcome will depend on how busy your replica set is. Since all members of the replica set have to write the same data, a significantly under-resourced member will be more likely to have replication lag and end up stale (requiring a resync). If you want to save on costs, I'd look into a free or low cost hosted service. For example, [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) has a free tier with 512MB storage.

Comment: The issue is that I need a very large storage since we're putting large files in GridFS. If the local replica is lagging behind, and gets regularly out of sync, has to catch up during the slow times, etc it's not a big deal; the important point is that it needs to not slow down the main server's operations.

Comment: A Raspberry Pi isn't well suited to large storage and isn't an officially supported platform for MongoDB. From the description so far I expect this won't work out well: if the Pi can't keep up with your workload and keeps requiring a resync, that will definitely have an impact (since all data would have to be fetched into memory for a full resync from another member of the replica set). In the general case a slow secondary will also increase the working set (and likely required oplog size) if there is significant replication lag.

Comment: I'd still recommend looking into a low cost hosting service as a better approach, but the best way to confirm would be to test with your workload.